# Scanning a String

Tags: java, string

My program reads a file called input.txt which somewhat looks like this:

```
Open  
Login 1000  
Deposit 99  
Quit
```

However in my code I have

```
String split[] = userInput.split(" ");  
int value      = Integer.parseInt(split[split.length -1]);
```

Which basically splits the 1000 from the string "Login 1000"

However my program seems to be reading the input file word by word.

Is there any way to read Login 1000  as one string?

Comment: Re, `"Reading a String with Java PrintWriter"` -- PrintWriter isn't used to **read** Strings. It **writes** them out. Perhaps you wish to use a Scanner? I'm not sure as your question is a bit unclear, and in fact your question is about String reading and yet you're not showing any String-reading code -- why?

Comment: I think he meant Scanner. He probably typed wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using `nextLine()` and not `next()`;

**Example:**

```
Scanner fScn = new Scanner(new File("File.txt"));
String data = fScn.nextLine();
```